# Unable to understand class definition in C++

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to disk-based R-trees although I have coded main memory based R-Trees. In order to understand disk based R-Trees I am using the library "libspatialIndex". While understanding the library I am coming across strange definitions of classes like the one given below:

```
class SIDX_DLL IStorageManager
{
public:
    virtual void loadByteArray(const id_type id, uint32_t& len, byte** data) = 0;
    virtual void storeByteArray(id_type& id, const uint32_t len, const byte* const data) = 0;
    virtual void deleteByteArray(const id_type id) = 0;
    virtual ~IStorageManager() {}
}; // IStorageManager
```

I fail to understand this new definition of class whereby it uses SIDX_DLL in the class definition. Can someone please give me pointers as to what does SIDX_DLL represent in the class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a macro that allows the same include be used from library clients and library implementation. Add attributes required to implement dynamic linking.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Did u use an IDE to understand which function is defined where. I am thus far viewing the file in text editor and then searching the definition of file by grep command. Is there an easy way by which I may get the function/class definitions quickly. Please help

Comment: I use QtCreator, where F2 jump to symbol definition.

Comment: how did u open the project libsptialindex in QTCreator..I am new to QTcreator..so can u please help...also can we also compile the project libspatialindex with QTCreator

Comment: If you use QtCreator in Windows you must choice GCC or MSVC. Please post another question about that, after completing your current question.

Comment: I am running QTcreator on linux with gcc...my problem is what are the executable that I should give in order to run RTreebulkLoad.

Comment: I presume that you have already built the library. Then make another project that uses the DLL: add -L path_to_DLL and -lspatialIndex and so on. It's difficult to go into any detail in a comment, and there are several other questions already answered about.

Comment: I can run the code within QTCreator...but when I debug the code it gives me the error that..."/spatialindex-src-1.8.0/test/rtree/RTreeBulkLoad": not in executable format: File format not recognized. Are u also getting the same error while debugging...

Comment: Sorry, it's going to be complicated, can't you open another question for QtCreator usage ?

Comment: I have already opened another question regarding its usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704663/qtcreator-does-not-recognize-the-executable-while-debugging-c-program

Answer (score 1):

Tools.h

```
47 #if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64 || defined WIN32 || defined WIN64
48  #ifdef SPATIALINDEX_CREATE_DLL
49  #define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
50  #else
51  #define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
52  #endif
53 #else
54  #define SIDX_DLL
55 #endif
```

That's just a macro, which adds compiler-specific attributes to class definition

Comment: Thanks for helping. Did u use an IDE to understand which function is defined where. I am thus far viewing the file in text editor and then searching the definition of file by grep command. Is there an easy way by which I may get the function/class definitions quickly. Please help

Comment: @user1778824 Nope, I've just googled SIDX_DLL to see it's definition =)

Answer (score 1):

`SIDX_DLL` is a macro. It's for making the `IStorageManager` symbol exported in a dll.

This kind of macros are usually defined like this:

```
 #if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(SIDX_EXPORTS)
 #  define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
 #elif defined(_MSC_VER)
 #  define SIDX_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
 #else
 #  define SIDX_DLL
 #endif
```

`SIDX_EXPORTS` is a MSVC-defined symbol that only gets defined when compiling the SIDX dll. In that case, `SIDX_DLL` expands to `__declspec(dllexport)`. In all other cases, it expands to `__declspec(dllimport)` — which imports the symbol to wherever it is used.

The empty `SIDX_DLL` (the last `#else` in the listing) is for non-Windows environments.

Comment: Why does one need to export a class definition in a dll

Comment: That's just the way MSVC works. If you don't export and try to use it somewhere outside the symbol's own dll, you'll get a linkage error.

Comment: Does MSVC stand for microsoft visual C++

Answer (score 0):

It's define. You can read about this at http://libspatialindex.github.com/doxygen/Tools_8h_source.html 54 row.

Answer (score 0):

It's a macro. It probably defines the dll import/export properties.

Go to its definition (F12), and you'll see that it is defined to `__declspec(import)` and `__declspec(export)`

Comment: Thanks for helping. Did u use an IDE to understand which function is defined where. I am thus far viewing the file in text editor and then searching the definition of file by grep command. Is there an easy way by which I may get the function/class definitions quickly. Please help

Comment: @user1778824 Macros after the class name are for __declspec ... you can use visual studio as an IDE, just load all the files into a project.

Comment: is there a way to do so the same in netbeans