# QTCreator does not recognize the executable while debugging C++ program

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have installed QTCreator in ubuntu 12.04 through sudo apt-get install. My problem is that QTcreator is not able to recognize the executable in debug mode, although it is running fine  without debugging..when I simply run my program. The error which the QTCreator throws at me while debugging is:

```
s/Prog": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I can use gdb outside QtCreator. All my tool chain just shows me GCC(x86 64 bit)...is this setting fine. If not please recommend.

Comment: Since there is problem in debug mode only - the problem is caused by gdb. See if you can use gdb outside QtCreator.

Comment: @VinayakGarg I can use gdb outside QtCreator. All my tool chain just shows me GCC(x86 64 bit)...is this setting fine. If not please recommend.

Comment: This may be your issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/275472/558094

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my `Ubuntu 13.10` and what I did was `sudo apt-get install gdb` and after that the debugger worked fine. What seemed strange for me, however, is that although I already had `gdb` and `gdb64` in `/usr/bin`, `apt` didn't say that `gdb` is already installed and it installed it(maybe an upgraded version).

Also check out your tool chain and make sure you're using `gdb 64-bit` if your executable is built on `64-bits`.

I use `Qt Creator 3.1.0`, maybe you should upgrade your `QtCreator` as well.

Hope this helps.